# How to authorize webapi endpoint for 3rd party to use

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, identityserver3

I have to create a endpoint that will use used by a 3rd party. We use identity server when people log in to our application. What do I need to do to only allow access to this 3rd party to call the endpoint? I dont want just anyone to be able to call the endpoint.
For example, if I gave you my endpoint URL and you used postman to post to it, I would only allow you if you were authorised

Comment: do you have CORS enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to secure an ASP.NET web app/api.

I typically use a SQL user store or active directory and issue JWT tokens. A nice guide can be found here.

https://jonhilton.net/2017/10/11/secure-your-asp.net-core-2.0-api-part-1---issuing-a-jwt/

Here is the documentation for identity server - as you mentioned you wanted to use that - about this very topic.

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/apis.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to enable CORS (Cross-Origin Requests) as [outlined by Microsoft here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api).

For example, you would decorate your controller as so:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace WebService.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "http://mywebclient.azurewebsites.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        // Controller methods not shown...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at that. But if I were to give you my api enpoint How can I prevent you from using postman to send a request if you are not authorised? I don't think CORS would help here

Comment: @user1024941 CORS allows you to specify what domains can call your API. You didnt really specify in your question where the calls would originate. This allows control access explicitly to domains you allow, even at a granular level.

Comment: @user1024941 I agree JWT Tokens are better for security at the user level.  My suggestion was for implementing security at the domain level. My apologies for my confusion.